# Django Admin - Cannot change <h2> color

Tags: html, css, django

I am learning Django.  I am customizing the Django Admin page.  I have created a base_site.html file in my templates to overwrite the default admin html.  Additionally, I have created a stylesheet that I've tied to it.

Here's my problem:  By default, there is a div on the right side of the content with an h2 header that states "Recent Actions."  I want to change this texts color, but my CSS won't seem to work on these words...

```
<div id="content-related">
    <div class="module" id="recent-actions-module">
        <h2>Recent actions</h2>
        <h3>My actions</h3>
        <p>None available</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried each of the following CSS:

```
#content-related{
    color: blue;
}
```

```
.module h2{
    color: blue;
}
```

```
#recent-actions-module h2{
    color: blue;
}
```

```
#content related h2{
    color: blue;
}
```

Nothing works... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a CSS that's loaded later than the snippets you posted here, that can easily make the issue to appear (later CSS takes precedence). I recommend to open the browser developer console, and inspect the headline - it should show you which CSS style is being used.

If you need some more help, we'd need your base_site.html.

Answer (score 0):

1. the following code should suffice for the CSS:

```
h2{color: blue;}
```

this applies to all future h2 tags on templates that are linked to your CSS file.
Otherwise, if you want it only for Recent Actions use this:

```
<div class="module></div?
```

And in CSS:

```
.module{color: blue;}
```

2. You are probably forgetting to link your CSS page. Use this:

```
&lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'CSS/base.css' %}">
```

Don't forget to add {% load static %} at the top of your html template.

3. I don't know why you would want to change your Admin page, because virtually noone except you would ever access it. If you are trying to create a portal for users to login view this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/
4. If you 3 is not the case, you should open up your browser's inspect element and view the webpage. Also to save yourself a buttload of time in creating the new look for your admin checkout the Django admin templates on Github.
   [Here](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin) are all the admin html templates to make your life easier.